# Alias an Ansible dict reference to `item` inside task?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible task that looks like this:

```
- name: Create cron job to backup foo (default is every day at 2AM )
  cron: name="foo-database-backup"
    cron_file="foo-database-backup"
    minute="{{ foo.backup_policy.minute|default('0') }}"
    hour="{{ foo.backup_policy.hour|default('2') }}"
    day="{{ foo.backup_policy.day|default('*') }}"
    weekday="{{ foo.backup_policy.weekday|default('*') }}"
    month="{{ foo.backup_policy.month|default('*') }}"
    job="/bin/true"
```

With a corresponding group_vars file that looks like this:

```
---
foo:
  backup_policy:
    minute: 30
    hour: 3
    day: "*/3"
```

However, I was wondering if I could make the task more readable and less error-prone when copying code snippets by aliasing the `foo.backup_policy` dict reference to `item` inside the task.  I tried doing so using `with_items` like this:

```
- name: Create cron job to backup foo (default is every day at 2AM )
  cron: name="foo-database-backup"
    cron_file="foo-database-backup"
    minute="{{ item.minute|default('0') }}"
    hour="{{ item.hour|default('2') }}"
    day="{{ item.day|default('*') }}"
    weekday="{{ item.weekday|default('*') }}"
    month="{{ item.month|default('*') }}"
    job="/bin/true"
  with_items: foo.backup_policy
```

But that doesn't work (as I pretty much expected) since `with_items` really wants a list or set (I get error `with_items expects a list or a set` if I try).

Is it possible to alias this dict to `item` or something shorter like that inside the task, or should I stop trying to micro-optimize things so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really the answer you were looking for, but you solved it yourself already anyway, so: You can as well improve readability by indenting the `cron` parameters all on the same level, like this:

```
- name: Create cron job to backup foo (default is every day at 2AM )
  cron: name="foo-database-backup"
        cron_file="foo-database-backup"
        minute="{{ item.minute|default('0') }}"
        hour="{{ item.hour|default('2') }}"
        day="{{ item.day|default('*') }}"
        weekday="{{ item.weekday|default('*') }}"
        month="{{ item.month|default('*') }}"
        job="/bin/true"
  with_items:
    - "{{ foo.backup_policy }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay this looks kind of weird, but I was able to get it to work by wrapping it in a Jinja template and putting it inside a single-element list:

```
- name: Create cron job to backup foo (default is every day at 2AM )
  cron: name="foo-database-backup"
    cron_file="foo-database-backup"
    minute="{{ item.minute|default('0') }}"
    hour="{{ item.hour|default('2') }}"
    day="{{ item.day|default('*') }}"
    weekday="{{ item.weekday|default('*') }}"
    month="{{ item.month|default('*') }}"
    job="/bin/true"
  with_items:
    - "{{ foo.backup_policy }}"
```

(`with_items: [ "{{ foo.backup_policy }}" ]` also works)

Maybe it's my familiarity with Ruby, but I guess I was always expecting that Jinja-interpolation-in-a-string to return a String type.